# How does happen the destruction of variables with a goto statement in C++?

Tags: c++, lifetime, goto

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    if (true) {
        int b = 3;
    label_one:
        cout << b << endl;
        int j = 10;
        goto label_one;
    }
}
```

In the code above `goto` jumps to label_one, making the variable `j` be destroyed and reconstructed in each cycle. But what happens to the `b` variable ? Is it destroyed and reconstructed too or it is never destroyed? According to C++ ISO:

> Transfer out of a loop, out of a block, or back past an initialized
> variable with automatic storage duration involves the destruction of
> objects with automatic storage duration that are in scope at the point
> transferred from but not at the point transferred to.

My interpretation is that all variables in `if` scope should be destroyed, but if thats the case, when are they re-initialized(variable `b` in my code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the quoted text says, a variable is destroyed during the `goto` only if it is in scope at the point of the `goto` statement, but *not* in scope at the destination label. `b` is in scope at both points, so it is not destroyed. Only `j` is destroyed.

Comment: What is the 'scope'? I'm thinking scope as the compound-statement `{code...}` so `label_one` and `goto` would have the same one.

Comment: @Roman The scope of a name is defined to be everywhere that name is visible. `j` is visible at the `goto` (in scope) but not visible at `label_one:` (not in scope). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: 'scope' is section 3.3 of the spec (6 pages) -- there are precise rules for when something is in scope and when it is not, but it basically comes down to the scope of a variable being from the declaration to the end of the block.

Comment: I thought "scope" would have the standard english meaning encoutered in a dictionary, Is there a 'hint' to not fall in this kind of thought?

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy one to test.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class X
{
    public:
        X()     {std::cout << "C\n";}
        ~X()    {std::cout << "D\n";}
};

int main() {
    if (true) {
        int b = 3;
label_one:
        cout << b << endl;
        X j;
        if (b >= 5) {
            return 0;
        }
        ++b;
        std::cout << "GOTO\n";
        goto label_one;
    }
}
```

Compile and Run:

```
> g++ -std=c++17 ty.cpp
> ./a.out
3
C
GOTO
D
4
C
GOTO
D
5
C
D
```

The only thing you need to think about what does "Destory" mean in the context of a "int" rather than a class type. Basically for an integer this is a no-op.

Comment: I'd be careful about recommending to just test these types of things. It's hard to tell between a positive result and accidental UB. You'd have to already be familiar with the rules of `goto` to know for sure that the test is meaningful, but if that were the case you probably wouldn't have to ask the question in the first place.